# JsonReader Exception in Android while parsing large JSON data

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting an exception when using the `JsonReader` class in android while parsing a large json data.

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was STRING
```

The json data is valid but I can't find out the reason for this exception!

Thanks a lot!

My Code :

```
    public void readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        reader.setLenient(true);
        try {
            readJsonObject(reader);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {

            reader.close();
        }

    }


    // Read Json From JsonReader Class

    public void readJsonObject(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {

            String name = reader.nextName();

            System.out.println(name.equals("result"));
            if (name.equals("result")) {
                reader.beginObject();

                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                    String josnParser = reader.nextName();

                    if (josnParser.equals(optionmaster)) { // Optionmaster
                        reader.beginArray();

                        while (reader.hasNext()) {

                            readJsonArray(reader);
                        }
                        reader.endArray();
                    } else {
                        reader.skipValue();
                    }

                }
                reader.endObject();

            } else {
                reader.skipValue();
            }
        }
        reader.endObject();

    }

    public void readJsonArray(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

        reader.beginObject();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {

            String name = reader.nextName();
            System.out.println(name); // Here is My Exception ....





     if (name.equals("om_id")&& reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {

             String om_id = reader.nextString();
     }
         else if (name.equals("om_multiselect")&& reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {      

             String om_multiselect = reader.nextString();
     }
         else if (name.equals("omlang_name")&& reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {

             String omlang_name = reader.nextString();
     }
         else if (name.equals("om_createdDate")&& reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {

             String om_createdDate = reader.nextString();
     }
         else
         {
 reader.skipValue();
 }


        }

        reader.endObject();

    }
```

And here's the JSON data:

```
 {
        "result": {
 "options": [
                {
                    "opt_id": "8",
                    "opt_om_id": "3",
                    "optlang_name": "test1"
                },
                {
                    "opt_id": "9",
                    "opt_om_id": "3",
                    "optlang_name": "test"
                }
            ],
            "optionmaster": [
                {
                    "om_id": "2",
                    "om_multiselect": "N",
                    "omlang_name": "Style",
                    "om_createdDate": "2012-08-25 01:37:57"
                },
                {
                    "om_id": "3",
                    "om_multiselect": "Y",
                    "omlang_name": "TEst",
                    "om_createdDate": "2012-08-25 01:37:57"
                }
            ]

        }
    }
```

Here is my sample code please review , i parsed options array successfully, the i couldn't parse optionmaster the error which appears when trying to parse "om_id"

Logcat:

```
 05-21 17:39:54.833: W/System.err(1116): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was STRING

 05-21 17:39:54.833: W/System.err(1116):    at android.util.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:390)
 05-21 17:39:54.843: W/System.err(1116):    at com.test.JsonParser.readJsonArray(JsonParser.java:174)
 05-21 17:39:54.843: W/System.err(1116):    at com.test.JsonParser.readJsonObject(JsonParser.java:135)
 05-21 17:39:54.843: W/System.err(1116):    at com.test.JsonParser.readJsonStream(JsonParser.java:49)
 05-21 17:39:54.843: W/System.err(1116):    at com.test.ItemListActivity$ApiSyncController.doInBackground(ItemListActivity.java:149)

 05-21 17:39:54.853: W/System.err(1116):    at com.test.ItemListActivity$ApiSyncController.doInBackground(ItemListActivity.java:1)
 05-21 17:39:54.853: W/System.err(1116):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

 05-21 17:39:54.853: W/System.err(1116):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)

 05-21 17:39:54.863: W/System.err(1116):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)

 05-21 17:39:54.863: W/System.err(1116):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

 05-21 17:39:54.863: W/System.err(1116):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 05-21 17:39:54.863: W/System.err(1116):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)........
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace and the relevant code snippet.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a name but was STRING
05-21 18:48:57.502: W/System.err(3631):  at android.util.JsonReader.nextName(JsonReader.java:390)
05-21 18:48:57.502: W/System.err(3631):  at com.tapendium.JsonParser.readJsonArray(JsonParser.java:299)
05-21 18:48:57.502: W/System.err(3631):  at com.tapendium.JsonParser.readJsonObject(JsonParser.java:144)
05-21 18:48:57.512: W/System.err(3631):  at

Comment: These are the stack trace log, i validated the josn using josnlint.com its a valid one and the exception i understand that the key is null but when i debug i can see the correct json in reader object ,

Comment: Can you post your code, please? Did you call beginArray() and beginObject() before calling nextName()? Did you call skipValue() if you are not intersted in a particular value? Hard to guess without seeing your code...

Comment: In your readJsonArray() you also have to read the value! Either call nextString(), nextDouble(), .. or skipValue() after reading the name. Otherwise your code will call nextName() in the second iteration of the loop and fail because the stack still contains the value of the first iteration.

Comment: Yes i allready did that..i missed to put that in my code

Comment: You are missing something, as there should be "05-21 18:48:57.502" somewhere in your json, but you don't show that.

Comment: yes there is date field but i also handled it..

Comment: That is where the problem is, so it may be in how you are handling it, but with incomplete information there is little we can help with.

Comment: @James Black ,i edited my code and json ,now its complete i think

Comment: If you get rid of the 'options' element and then just keep the one, and see what happens, as the error message and what you are showing seem to differ as it is complaining that where there is a name it gets a string.

Comment: @James Black, The exception raised when the "optionmaster" arrays first iteration starts, after getting "om_id" its trying to parse next name "om_multiselect" but getting the "N" value there not Token name, i doubt is there any bug that happening in JsonReader class

Comment: I have a concearn that the short circuit && (and) doesn't execute the reader.peek()

Comment: Same error i am getting .

Answer (score 0):

I have a concearn with the short circuit and the check for reader.peek not executing.
Do the reader.peek() check first then go over your ifs

```
if (reader.peek()!=JsonToken.NULL) {
    if (name.equals("om_id")) {
        String om_id = reader.nextString();
    } else if (name.equals("om_multiselect")) {      
        String om_multiselect = reader.nextString();
    } else if (name.equals("omlang_name")) {
        String omlang_name = reader.nextString();
    } else if (name.equals("om_createdDate")) {
        String om_createdDate = reader.nextString();
    } else {
        reader.skipValue();
    }
}
```

Good Luck